# Beginning index of every word

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the beginning index of every word in a string. Word is defined by anything non whitespace character.

```
String test = "this that and that";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\s+[WHAT TO WRITE HERE]\\s+").matcher(test);
        while (matcher.find()) {
          System.out.println(matcher.start());
        }
```

What should I write in the regular expression? For e.g. the output should be 0,5,10,14
There can be multiple whitespaces between words.

Comment: Why not just match `"\\S+"`?

Comment: Could you please post that as an answer? I will accept it. But out of curiosity, is there any way to do the way I am doing?

Comment: See my answer; your loop is correct and does what you intend it to do. No problem there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Word is defined by anything non whitespace character.

And there is a character class for that: `\S`.

Your regex should therefore be:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\S+");
```

Note however that the definition of "word" you have is rather large; this will also include punctuation etc.

As to your loop, it is correct, since when you have a match, the `Matcher`'s `.start()` method will indeed contain the index at which the match has started.

Taking your code and modifying it a little, this gives:

```
String test = "this that and that";
Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(test);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start());
}
```

Comment: But what is this animal?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte what animal? My avatar?

Comment: @fge, Thanks. Your answer is indeed what I asked but more than "getting" the right answer, I want to know what I can do with my regular expression to make it work. I want to learn rather than get the answer. Could you please tell me what I could have written?

Comment: @IanMcGrath well, you said you wanted to print the index of the beginning of each word; your while loop is correct. What do you want more? How to return a list of indices?

Comment: @fge, no, I want to know what I could have written in the "WHAT TO WRITE HERE" in the code. If there is any way to do that.

Comment: Be careful, this answer does not get the index of every word, it gets the index of every space. Check my answer.

Comment: @IanMcGrath well you won't get what you want with the "regex template" you have, since you start and match one space character or more; you would therefore never have the index of the beginning of each word, EXCEPT if you took the matched string and tried and find the first non space index and add that to the .start() of each match . Rather painful and counterproductive!

Comment: @JaviFernández absolutely not. What makes you think that?

Comment: @fge Using the regex you suggest in the code provided the result is `4`, `9` and `13`, the indexes of the spaces in the sentence

Comment: I didn't know that Taz comes from a real animal!

Comment: @fge now I know I need glasses :P my apologies!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use this regex:

```
...
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]+").matcher(test);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use :

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

It will find only alpha-numeric word.
I think "\S+" will be problematic with punctuation marks and weird chars.
You can even drop the numeric ("0-9") part if you want.

Answer (score 1):

@fge already gave the best answer but since I can't reply to his comment. @Ian McGrath you were asking what you could have written well other solutions exist. This is what I came up with and it seemed to work also.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\w+?(\\s+|$)").matcher(test);
```